# How do i push login page if there is no internet connection

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3

i want to always show whether `internet` `connection` is there or not? without

`subscribing` for `network` `changes`.

**My Question: on launch of the app i want to check internet connection. if it is not there i want to present `notification`**

here is what i have done:

**if there is no internet connection then i want to push login page**

**the below code works `perfect` on `network` `changes`  but i'm unable to detect the status whether it connected or not to push loginPage?**

```
  displayNetworkUpdate(connectionState: string){
    let networkType = this.network.type;


    this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: `You are now ${connectionState} via ${networkType}`,
      duration: 3000
    }).present();
  }




  ionViewDidEnter() {

       this.network.onConnect().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.displayNetworkUpdate(data.type);
      }, error => console.error(error));

      this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.displayNetworkUpdate(data.type);
      }, error => console.error(error));


  }
```

**the above code works `perfect` on `network` `changes`  but i'm unable to detect the status whether it connected or not to push loginPage?**

Answer (score 0):

In your root component, watch for `offline` event

```
window.addEventListener('offline', ()=>{
    // your logic
});
```

Comment: could you explain this code a bit, so that i will implement? please

Comment: This is a window event for internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link,

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

constructor(private network: Network) { }

if (this.network.type === 'none') {
   console.log('No connection');
}
```

Comment: @Eab : If you find my answer working for you, then you can approve it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below method in constructor of first page you want to launch. On disconnect close the active portals like modals, toast and overlay manually as navigating to other page (Network page - page with no internet message or login page) will not close the active portals.

```
import {IonicApp  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
```

Import Ionic App and network to run the below code

```
this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        let activePortal = this.ionicApp._loadingPortal.getActive() ||
        this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive() ||
        this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive() ||
         this.ionicApp._overlayPortal.getActive();


       //activePortal is the active overlay like a modal,toast,etc
        if (activePortal) {
          activePortal.dismiss();
      }
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(NetworkPage);
      });
```